# DNN Module compiler error: CS

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Module Creator templates for Dotnetnuke 7 trying to make our staff sign in-out module function. Am working with code developed by a volunteer intern from France years ago for DNN 5 Beta. (Some of the spelling is French) I am not a coder myself so am struggling to make the code work in DNN 7. I've managed to figure out a lot of the compiling errors by reading this web site. Thank you. This one has me absolutely stumped:

```
Error: France is currently unavailable.
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException:
d:\HostingSpaces\tgpintra\tgpintranet.org\wwwroot\DesktopModules\TGP\France\View.ascx.cs(176): error CS1010: Newline in constant --->
```

The source code starting at line 175 is below:

```
                //Set the parameters for updating user's information
            SqlUpdate.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Scotland SET 

statut=@statut, timereturn=@timereturn, date=@date, comment=@comment 

WHERE name='"  +

DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Username + 

"'";
            SqlUpdate.UpdateParameters.Add("statut", 

DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
            SqlUpdate.UpdateParameters.Add("timereturn", 

timereturn.Text);
            SqlUpdate.UpdateParameters.Add("date", DateTime.Now.AddHours

(-2).ToString());
            SqlUpdate.UpdateParameters.Add("comment", comment.Text);
            SqlUpdate.Update();
            //Insert a log for the user and his/her new status
            SqlConnection MaSqlCnx = new SqlConnection();
            MaSqlCnx.ConnectionString = "Server=someserver.

net;Initial Catalog=tgpintra_db;User 

Id=theusername;Password=thepassword;";
            MaSqlCnx.Open();
            SqlCommand MaSqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            MaSqlCmd.Connection = MaSqlCnx;
            MaSqlCmd.CommandText = "Insert into ScotlandSchedule(name, 

status, time) Values('" + 

DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().FullName + 

"', '" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "', '" + DateTime.Now.AddHours(-

2).ToString() + "');";
            MaSqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MaSqlCnx.Close();

            //Reload the page to update data
            Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "1");
        }
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, this code is full of fail in terms of SQL injection attacks. I would suggest you find a coder you trust to rework it *properly* using parameterized SQL...

Comment: Posting passwords to DB access is questionable practice. Please consider to remove account information from your post AND change user credentials in your system...

Comment: I would just go with the latter. You will certainly have to change your credentials now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line breaks in the assignment to `SqlUpdate.UpdateCommand`. You can only have it on one line.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Our server failed so am just now getting back to this project. I see I am way over my head and will try to locate a coder to help me with this. Also change my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places that will cause this error:

```
SqlUpdate.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE ...
```

and

```
MaSqlCnx.ConnectionString = "Server=mssql02 ...
```

The strings in the lines above each need to be on a single line, or have a @ character before the opening " character.